# Webpack define module variable prefixing window

Tags: webpack

Webpack config:

```
const webpackConfig = {
  mode: WEBPACK_MODE,
  output: {
    library: 'lib',
    filename: 'library.js'
  },
  module: {
  ...
  }
```

Currently webpack compiles library.js file like:

```
var lib = {...}
```

What I need is:

```
window.lib = {...}
```

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the output.libraryTarget which does exactly this.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...
  libraryTarget: 'window',
  ...
};
```

Comment: libraryTarget: 'window'. Thank you!